# Variable for each result in WHILE loop SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a question about PHP `WHILE` loops. I know that you can perform the action mysql_num_rows to get the number of results from a `SELECT` query.

But say I have 3 results come through the select query and i put them through a while loop, how do I assign a variable to the number each result is in the `mysql_num_row`.

Such as
1 for result 1
2 for result 2
3 for result 3.
Sorry if this is a bit confusing, but i can't seem to find an easy way to explain it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
$results = array();
While ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$results[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myArray[] = $row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res=array();
$i=0;
While(mysql_fetch_array(...)){
$i++;
$res[$i]=value
//do logic
}
```

Comment: @nkr thought that obvious. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few 'new' methods for pulling back data from MySQL now, if you're just starting out this might be the ideal time to have a look at them. This looks like a good place to start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.